# Run Nodemon with Typescript compiling?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code, nodemon

I want my typescript files to be compiled on every file saving with the command `tsc`.

How do I combine the tsc command with the command that nodemon runs in the `build:live` script

```js
"scripts": {
    "start": "npm run build:live",
    "build:live": "nodemon --watch '*.ts' --exec 'ts-node' app.ts",
 }
```

this script causes nodemon to call itself twice or three times:

```
"build:live": "nodemon --watch '*.ts' --exec 'ts-node app.ts & tsc'",
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This looks like it will achieve what you're looking for:

```
"start": "tsc-watch --project . --outDir ./dist --onSuccess \"nodemon ./dist/bin/www.js\""
```

Source: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12996#issuecomment-349277673

Comment: This solved my exact problem. I wanted the TS to transpile, make sure the transpilation was successful and then run a specific file in dist. Thank you!

Answer (score 45):

Nodemon will detect and run `.ts` files with `ts-node` automatically now. It will actually run `.py` and `.rb` files with python and ruby too btw and you can give it a custom `--exec` for others. Here's a [link to the relevant code](https://github.com/remy/nodemon/blob/886527f1f0a9249e1a044fd652b7519d1c0dc50e/lib/config/defaults.js#L7-L14) within nodemon.

So the following should be fine:

```
"scripts": {
  "dev": "nodemon app.ts"
}
```

Answer (score 13):

With the current answer you might run into issues using ES modules.
No need for nodemon when you're using `tsc-watch`. It makes use of incremental compilation, making the restart of your application much faster.

I found the following to work best:

```
"start": "tsc-watch --onSuccess \"node ./dist/app.js\""
```

The `outDir` can be defined in your `tsconfig`

Answer (score 6):

As of TypeScript 3.8+, you can now just use:

```
tsc --watch
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/configuring-watch.html

You could then use `nodemon` on the compiled code, e.g. `nodemon dist/app.js`.

Comment: this is the correct answer! thank you.

Answer (score 5):

You can create a nodemon.json in your project root directory and add the following code inside that:

```json
{
 "ext": "*.ts",
 "exec": "tsc && ts-node app.ts"
}
```

And update your scripts like following:

```json
"scripts": {
   "start": "npm run build:live",
   "build:live": "nodemon",
}
```

What happens is that nodemon will check all the files with the extension ".ts" and starts tsc and then ts-node.

Comment: this worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

I'm using nodemon + concurrently libraries:

```
"watch": "concurrently \"npm run build -- --watch\" \"nodemon --watch '**/*' --exec npm run start\"",
```

build script:

```
"build": "tsc"
```