# nodemon clean exit - waiting for changes before restart

Tags: javascript, typescript, express, nodemon

I am working on a boiler plate for a typescript based express server. One of my key requirements is to have eslint running with nodemon. In my package.json i have...

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node dist/index.js",
    "dev": "nodemon src/index.ts --exec 'eslint . --ext .ts'",
    "build": "tsc -p ."
},
```

my express app is pretty simple at this point...

```
import express from 'express';
import { PORT } from './config/constants';

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());

app.get('/api-v1', (req, res) => {
    const test = 3;
    console.log(test);
    res.send('Hello World');
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is listening on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

so when I run the dev script `"nodemon src/index.ts --exec 'eslint . --ext .ts'"` the linting runs, however the express server is never started...I see this in the console:

`[nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart`

any thoughts on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The source code is [here](https://github.com/remy/nodemon/blob/7e00a30d31c5a464f7a2bee0657a4aa5e702236a/lib/monitor/run.js#L230)

I suppose `nodemon` expects to run a server (which never exits) but the command exited with code 0 (which is successful exit code).

Seems like `nodemon` call is incorrect.

It currently runs `eslint . --ext .ts src/index.ts` (which runs successfully and exits with code 0).

I think it should be something like this (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57998762/run-nodemon-with-typescript-compiling) for other options):

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node dist/index.js",
    "dev": "tsc-watch --project . --outDir ./dist --onSuccess \"nodemon dist/index.js\"",
    "build": "tsc -p ."
},
```